# Why does spam package and maps package in R have different numbers of counties in the contiguous US?

Tags: r, maps, spam

The `UScounties.storder` function in the `spam` package returns a neighborhood matrix for the counties in the contiguous US, which specifies whether county `j` is a neighbor of county `i`. According to the documentation for `UScounties.storder`:

> We consider that two counties are neighbors if they share at least one edge of their polygon description in `maps`.

However, the number of counties according to the `maps` package and the `spam` package seem to be different:

```
library(maps)
library(spam)
length(map('county', plot = FALSE)$names)
```

returns `3085`. But

```
nrow(UScounties.storder)
```

returns `3082`.

Why are the number of counties different?

Comment: I know for a fact that hidalgo texas county is wrong in the maps package.  I think it has to with updated county lines.

Comment: The `maps` package is definitely not keeping up with the times. It even still has "USSR" as a valid country name. That's one reason I made [ggcounty](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/ggcounty). It doesn't currently have a quick way to get such a count, but there's a good chance it has the missing/different counties.

Comment: `ggcounty` seems to be good. Thanks, @hrbrmstr